# iOS support for DNS over TLS : native config possible, third party available, or not yet implemented?

Tags: ios, swift, security, networking, network-programming

As some might know, Google will implement DNS over TLS as standard in upcoming Android versions. My question is, does Apple have this capability available as well? Or, is there a third-party pod/framework available to meet this end?

If not, does anyone know of a brute-code approach to this, or if it might be a matter of implementing certain parameters in `info.plist` such as `NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` that you set for `Exception Domains`?

Any guidance or insight welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

iOS 11 provides an extension point for that. 
However this extension can be deployed to only supervised devices. (MDM)
You can’t deploy DNS-TLS extension to normal users through AppStore yet.

Comment: This is not true. Normal app store apps can implement a PacketTunnelProvider extension.

Comment: The extension point was private when OP asked. That's the reason I entered "YET".

Comment: Sorry I should be more clear: you are correct that the NEDNSProxyProvider is managed only, however you can do the same thing by running a VPN, setting the DNS server in the configuration, and then only routing traffic destined for that server over your VPN. This is what Cloudflare does.